# SQL add missing dates from the latest date to current date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a currency table which gets filled in monthly. so, 3rd of every month, data for last month is getting updated.

All I want is to have the entries from the latest date to the current date. 
If the last entry for a specific combination was found on 1st Feb 2020, I need to fill in my currency table such that there are entries from 1st Feb to Current date for that combination, 
The combination is basically - Type of currency, From Currency and to Currency.

I know Lead() function is the key to this but I am not able to understand how exactly to use it.

Giving a small example below:

Existing entries:

```
timestamp type fcurr tcurr Conv_ratio
20200101   M    EUR   USD    0.9
20200201   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200229   C    INR   EUR    0.4
```

Expected output:

```
timestamp type fcurr tcurr Conv_ratio
20200101   M    EUR   USD    0.9
20200201   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200202   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200203   M    EUR   USD    0.85
.
.
.
20200424   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200229   C    INR   EUR    0.4
20200301   C    INR   EUR    0.4
20200302   C    INR   EUR    0.4
.
.
20200424   C    INR   EUR    0.4
```

Ideal output I am looking it is as below but even if I cant get this, above output is fine for me.

```
timestamp type fcurr tcurr Conv_ratio
20200101   M    EUR   USD    0.9
20200201   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200301   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200401   M    EUR   USD    0.85
20200229   C    INR   EUR    0.4
20200331   C    INR   EUR    0.4
```

Basically there are entries for 1st of every month for type M and last of every month for type C.

Comment: mysql or sqlserver that is the question.And what versions are you on.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server or Snowflake? Please tag the actual RDBMS you are using as they are quite different.

Comment: my apologies. It's for snowflake data warehouse

Comment: your entries have id column?

Comment: Are there any other currencies? Or there are just EUR/USD and INR/EUR ?

Comment: many currencies are there.. This is just a small example.. All currencies to all other currencies

Comment: I'm lost.  "Expected output" or "ideal output"?  I also don't get where the dates are coming from.

Comment: @SagarMorakhia If you dont have id in your data table and my answer does not work for you I can modify it to work without id column too.But it is better to have an id as a primary key in your table

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that there are only 2 currencies, but it seems there can be more. So I updated my query to process all currencies. Here is my sample table:

```
create or replace table currencies (ctimestamp varchar, ctype varchar, 
fcurr varchar, tcurr varchar, conv_ration number(3,2) )
as select * from values  
('20200101' ,  'M' , 'EUR' , 'USD'  ,  0.9),
('20200201' ,  'M' , 'EUR' ,  'USD' ,   0.85),
('20200229' ,  'C' , 'INR' ,  'EUR' ,   0.4);
```

Here is my solution which does not use any temporary tables or stored procedures, but just SQL:

```
with generated_days as 
(select to_varchar( dateadd( days, row_number() over (order by 1) - 1, (select min(to_date(ctimestamp,'YYYYMMDD')) from currencies)), 'YYYYMMDD' ) gtimestamp 
from table(generator(rowcount => 10000))
),
first_last_days as
(select gtimestamp, IFF(substring(gtimestamp, -2 ) = '01', 'M', 'C' ) mc
from generated_days where ( substring(gtimestamp, -2 ) = '01' or last_day( to_date(gtimestamp,'YYYYMMDD')) = to_date(gtimestamp,'YYYYMMDD'))   
and to_date(gtimestamp,'YYYYMMDD') <= current_date
),
curtypes as 
(select ctype || fcurr || tcurr pkey, ctype, max(ctimestamp) max_date from currencies group by ctype || fcurr || tcurr, ctype),
combination as (
select pkey, gtimestamp, null ctype, null fcurr, null tcurr, null conv_ration
from first_last_days
join curtypes on gtimestamp > max_date and ctype = mc 
union all
select ctype || fcurr || tcurr pkey, * from currencies
order by pkey, gtimestamp)
select  
gtimestamp, left( pkey, 1 ) ctype,
NVL(fcurr, lag( fcurr, 1, NULL ) ignore nulls over (partition by pkey order by gtimestamp )) fcurr,
NVL(tcurr, lag( tcurr, 1, NULL ) ignore nulls over (partition by pkey order by gtimestamp )) tcurr,
NVL(conv_ration, lag( conv_ration, 1, NULL ) ignore nulls over (partition by pkey order by gtimestamp)) conv_ration
from combination
order by ctype, fcurr, tcurr, gtimestamp;
```

First I generate dates, then select only first and last days of each month. I group existing data by each currency and ctype. I join these groups with available dates and merge with existing values. I fill the missing values using LAG function.

Here is the result of the above query:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| GTIMESTAMP | CTYPE | FCURR | TCURR | CONV_RATION |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   20200229 | C     | INR   | EUR   |        0.40 |
|   20200331 | C     | INR   | EUR   |        0.40 |
|   20200101 | M     | EUR   | USD   |        0.90 |
|   20200201 | M     | EUR   | USD   |        0.85 |
|   20200301 | M     | EUR   | USD   |        0.85 |
|   20200401 | M     | EUR   | USD   |        0.85 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: @SagarMorakhia I modified the query to cover all currencies - at least it seems working on my tests.